# How to retry in Rundeck

Tags: rundeck

I made job including a few step(Job Reference) and set to retry the step if it fails.
But just now I found that it does not work (chapter [Retry] of http://rundeck.org/docs/manual/jobs.html)

Does anybody know other way?

Answer (score 1):

Retry only affects the job if is invoked directly

> Retry
>
> You can set a maximum number of retries for a job. If a job
>   fails or times out, it will be executed again up to the specified
>   number of times until it succeeds. (**Note: Retry only affects the job
>   if is invoked directly, not if it is used as a Job Reference.**)

[Rundeck Doc - Jobs](http://rundeck.org/docs/manual/jobs.html#retry)